# Why the used disk space increases after yum update?

Tags: yum, centos-6

If I do a `yum update` on a fresh CentOS 6.5 image, its disk usage increases by 200 MB. The image is a custom AWS image built some 6 months ago. The base image is almost barebones and takes around 1GB. Is there way to reduce the disk space used after the `yum update`?

Comment: Because yum downloads the updates, and updates tend to be larger than their previous version.

Comment: Thats true. But, the yum download size shows as around 80 MB. Does yum holds onto the downloaded package files. If yes, how to get rid of the downloaded package files.

Comment: What's the value of `keepcache` in `/etc/yum.conf`?

Comment: keepcache is 0. Which means it should delete the downloaded file, right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yum clean packages
```

Should clear the cache